# Best path for management actions in Active Directory with .net Core 3.1 from an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, .net-core-3.1

I need to perform the following actions in Active Directory:

- find if a group exists
- create a group
- delete all members of a group
- add users to a group

This was done by a webservice that was hosted on IIS and had .net framework 4.7.1 runtime.

Now, we are moving to Azure and we plan on creating a Azure Function to host this webservice. However, the code is now in .net core 3.1 and does not support using "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement". There is a possibility of installing the library from Nuget, although it downgrades Microsoft.NETCore.Platform from 3.1.0 to 2.0.0 (which is something I don't know if it can affect my code in .net core 3.1)
[image: NetCore downgrade]

Even if I install this library, from what I understand, this functionality was no longer supported for .net core and has been added just for compatibility. So if this is being deprecated, there should be a better way to do this actions for .net core.

- Do I need to use Azure Active Directory instead?
- Is there a new library that substituted System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?
- how should I approach this solution?

Thank you very much for your time!